In SharePoint's new Banner webpart the font color is black and that has been fixed even after I changed the Theme. tried custom CSS also but not work
In SharePoint's new Banner webpart, the font color is black, which has been fixed even after I changed the Theme. I tried custom CSS but that also did not work. May I know any other way to do it?
